# Performing simulations and combining the data into one data frame

Tags: r, simulation

For each reported study, I want to do 1000 simulations of a parameter X using normal or log-normal distribution (based on a flag) and then combine all the simulations in one data frame. I am looking for an automated way of doing this.

What I have is a data frame with the following columns:

```
SOURCE  NSUB   MEAN   SD   DIST
Study1  10     1.5    0.3  0
Study2  5      2.5    0.4  1
Study1  4      3.5    0.3  0
```

when `DIST==0` then it is normal distribution, if `DIST==1` then it is log-normal.

I am able to do the simulations and combine them using hard coding: for example:

```
#for Study1:
set.seed <-1
NSUB <- 10
MEAN <- 1.5
SD   <- 0.3
DIST <- 0   #Normal distribution

df1 <- data.frame("SOURCE"="Study1","NSUB"=NSUB,"DIST"=DIST, "VALUE" = rnorm(1000, mean=MEAN, sd=SD))

#For study2
set.seed <-2
NSUB <- 5
MEAN <- 2.5
SD   <- 0.4
DIST <- 1   #log-normal distribution
df2 <- data.frame("SOURCE"="Study2","NSUB"=NSUB,"DIST"=DIST, "VALUE" = rlnorm(1000, meanlog=log(MEAN), sdlog=SD))

#Combine all
dfall <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

However, this would be tedious to me I have alot of reported means and SD for the parameter. I need help in how to make this automated so it does 1000 simulation for each row (using MEAN and SD) and then combine all simulated data in one data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of implementing readable and general code, you should do two things here:

1. Write a function that takes each row of your simulation configuration dataset and returns the simulated values as a `data_frame` (`doSim` below). This makes it easier to test your simulation code separately from your iteration over simulation configurations.
2. Use `dplyr` to pass each row of the function to this function, and collect up the results as a `data_frame`.

Here is some sample code:

```
library(dplyr)

# read in the simultation configuration dataset
dfX = read.table(textConnection("
                 SOURCE  NSUB   MEAN   SD   DIST
Study1  10     1.5    0.3  0
Study2  5      2.5    0.4  1
Study1  4      3.5    0.3  0"),
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# write a function that takes each row of the configuration
#   data.frame and returns the simulations
doSim = function(simConfig, seed = 12345) {
  set.seed(seed)
  dist = if(simConfig[["DIST"]] == 0) rnorm else rlnorm
  mean = if(simConfig[["DIST"]] == 0) simConfig[["MEAN"]] else log(simConfig[["MEAN"]]) 
  return(
    data_frame(
      source = simConfig[["SOURCE"]],
      nsub = simConfig[["NSUB"]],
      value = dist(1000, mean = mean, sd = simConfig[["SD"]])
    )
  )
}

# test the function
doSim(dfX[1, ])

# apply over dfX
dfX %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(doSim(.))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is really useful!. if it is log-normal distribution then it should be using the log[[MEAN]] rather than the mean as it is. if normal distributed, then the [[MEAM]] is used. An if statement for the `value` will fix this.

Comment: Also, would it be possible to set a seed for the simulations so we can produce the same results if we do the simulation again?

Comment: @Amer Edited to include both the changes.